# How to develop a javascript library from an already existing npm module (codius)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

never done this before.

I'm using https://github.com/codius/codius-host. Codiu§ development has been abandoned, but I want to salvage part of it to use for my own project. I really need to be able to run codius commands from browser, so I need to develop a library or what you call it.

```
var codius = require('codius')

codius.upload({host: http://contract.host}
```

codius-host comes packed with command-line integration,

```
$ CODIUS_HOST=https://codius.host codius upload
```

How do I make a .js script do what the command-line command does ?

also posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126511/if-i-have-a-npm-tool-that-uses-comman-line-commands-how-can-i-create-a-javascri
hard time asking this questions since don't know where to start. help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to the codius-host source code you should find the piece of code which manages the command line arguments. I am sure that they do handle the command and the command line arguments from an entry module/function and than later delegate the real job to a different module/function. What you need to do is to provide correct parameters to the functions which the function/module that handles command line argument calls with command line parameters.

In addition to that there are some nodejs libraries that might imitate a command line call from the program itself. One of those I know is shelljs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs

You might want to check this out as well. With this one without bothering with the source code you might be able to imitate command line behaviour.

Comment: thanks ! I found it the piece of code that manages the command line arguments,
https://github.com/codius/codius-cli/blob/d08fbf5c635ba929f0b6515c9c25cc12ab433cec/lib/codius.js

I should be able to find my way from there !

Comment: cool! you can select the answer as the correct answer if you think it was the answer you are looking for.